# How to show only the pod name when hovering Grafana chart from Kubernetes "container_memory_usage_bytes" metric?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, metrics

I created this chart using Grafana and the query
`rate(container_memory_usage_bytes{ image!="", container_name!="POD"}[5m]) /1024 / 1024`.

When highlighting the data points I receive all the details about the pod that is too much information.

How can I show only the `pod` field?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: go to Options / Legend and include the field to be used as legend :) In this case: `{{pod}}`

[image]

Thanks [Fabio Vieira](https://www.linkedin.com/in/fabiotavaresvieira/)